# Avoid the 'Access Denied when calling the ListBuckets operation' Error with Python Boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, access-denied

I'm completely new on AWS and anyone has given me the credentials of a S3 bucket (url, access key, secret key and region) in order to let me upload files. I would like to be able to connect to the S3 bucket with Python & Boto3 but when I tried:

```
import boto3

aws_access_key_id = 'XXX'
aws_secret_access_key = 'XXX'
aws_region = 'eu-west-1'
bucket_url = 'https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/XXX?region=eu-west-1'

s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
    region_name=aws_region)

response = s3.list_buckets()
```

The following error is returned when list_buckets() is called:
`ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied`

Do you know why? And how to fix it please? What should I do to be able to list files and upload ones?

Thanks.

Comment: Check IAM role permissions and ensure [you allow access to ListBucket](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-listobjects-sync/)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry but I didn't understand well how to achieve that.
Do I need to create an 'Access Point' with the given JSON policy in the URL of the S3 Bucket? 
Or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: When I'm the bucket url and I click on 'Permissions' (between 'Properties' and 'Metrics' in the menu), I see in the section 'Permissions overview': Access Unavailable. Does that I mean I simply just need to contact the owners of the S3 bucket to grant me the access to it? But then, why use an access / secret key?

Comment: Are you trying to view all the buckets owned by the user or just a single known bucket's objects? If the latter is the case you do not want `list_buckets`, but [`list_objects`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects)